How do I add file association for a user-made filetype
I am trying to make my own programming language and I can't seem to find a way to add file association to it. My language's name is pangolinScript and the extension is *.pa. How do I make vscode associate *.pa with pangolinScript even though pangolinScript is not recognized by vscode?
